# Sum a unique/distinct value in a Pivot Table - possible?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to make my pivot table sum a unique/distinct count of a score instead of every instance. Does anyone know of a way this might be possible? I basically only want to sum the first instance of a open and not all of them.

[image: Pivot table issue]

Thanks!

Comment: why not dedupe the source data?

Comment: How would you dedupe the source data Fabricator? Some records might have 1 open so they should remain untouched, but others might have 2 - multiple opens. I have about 10 thousand rows and im not really keen to do that by hand.

Comment: http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/distinct-count-in-pivot-tables-finally-in-excel-2013/

Comment: Thanks mate! - No exactly what i wanted but it will do :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag for first entry for each open using a if then statement and put a filter for that flag to count unique opens